# No implementation found for native Stitch

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I use opencv stitching in android project.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private String mWarpType;
    private String mMatchConf;
    private String mConfThresh;

    private SharedPreferences mSettings;
    public static final String SETTINGS                = "Pano_Settings";

    private final String SETTINGS_WARP_TYPE            = "warp";
    private final String SETTINGS_MATCH_CONF           = "match_conf";
    private final String SETTINGS_CONF_THRESH          = "conf_thresh";

    private String mDefaultWarpType                    = "spherical";
    private String mDefaultMatchConf                   = "0.5";
    private String mDefaultConfThresh                  = "0.8";
    ...

    public native int Stitch(Object[] args);    

    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.GoButton:

          List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
          s.add("Stitch");
          s.add("/sdcard/tesseract/images1.jpeg");
          s.add("/sdcard/tesseract/images2.jpeg");

          s.add("--warp");
          s.add(mWarpType);
          s.add("--conf_thresh");
          s.add(mConfThresh);
          s.add("--match_conf");
          s.add(mMatchConf);

          s.add("--work_megapix");
          s.add("0.2");
          s.add("--seam_megapix");
          s.add("0.2");
          s.add("--expos_comp");
          s.add("gain");
          s.add("--output");
          s.add("/sdcard/tesseract/");

          Integer i = Stitch(s.toArray());
          Log.d("1",i.toString());
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }

}
```

application is started but when Stitch(s.toArray()) is called I get the error:

```
W/dalvikvm(15392): No implementation found for native Lcom/prototype/MainActivity;.Stitch ([Ljava/lang/Object;)I
```

OpenCV successfully added in the workplace and my project -> Properties -> Android -> Library add -> OpenCV lib project
version OpenCV 2.4.2. 
sample was taken from the project android-opencv-panorama.

Comment: does your native c file have a function name Stitch which accepts your object and returns integer??

Comment: It seems that you don't have native implementarion of this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably copied the native code "as is" from the sample, but your Java class has a different package and name. Look for the function named `Java_<some more>_Stitch()` in your cpp file, and rename it to become:

```
Java_com_prototype_MainActivity_Stitch()
```