# No implementation found for native, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk, devil, android-ndk-r7

Okay before you flag this as a duplicate I have tried the following

[No implementation found for native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096355/no-implementation-found-for-native)

[No implementation found for native Stitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968366/no-implementation-found-for-native-stitch)

[No Implementation found for native in ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386204/no-implementation-found-for-native-in-ndk)

[No implementation found for native Lcom/jp/algi/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285651/no-implementation-found-for-native-lcom-jp-algi)

[Android NDK C++ JNI (no implementation found for native...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197889/android-ndk-c-jni-no-implementation-found-for-native)

[Android NDK: No implementation found for native xxxxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978197/android-ndk-no-implementation-found-for-native-xxxxxx)

here is my MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("physfs");
    System.loadLibrary("jpeg");
    System.loadLibrary("tiff");
    System.loadLibrary("mng");
    System.loadLibrary("png");
    System.loadLibrary("jasper");
    System.loadLibrary("lcms");
    System.loadLibrary("devil");
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
    }

public static native void convert();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    convert();
}
```

}

the c file

```
#include "com_myproject_MainActivity.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myproject_MainActivity_convert
  (JNIEnv *, jclass){
.....
}
```

the javah generated header snippet

```
#define com_myproject_MainActivity_DEFAULT_KEYS_SHORTCUT 2L
#undef com_myproject_MainActivity_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL
#define com_myproject_MainActivity_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL 3L
#undef com_myproject_MainActivity_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_GLOBAL
#define com_myproject_MainActivity_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_GLOBAL 4L
/*
 * Class:     com_myproject_MainActivity
 * Method:    convert
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myproject_MainActivity_convert
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

the portion of the android.mk file that sources the C file

```
#mylib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libmylib
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -g -Dlinux -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY=1 -DPHYSFS_NO_CDROM_SUPPORT=1 -DAL_ALEXT_PROTOTYPES=1 -DHAVE_GCC_DESTRUCTOR=1 -DOPT_GENERIC -DREAL_IS_FLOAT
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := ${LOCAL_CFLAGS}
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  :=  \
    ${DEVIL_SRC_PATH}include \
    ${DEVIL_SRC_PATH}src-IL/include \
    ${JASPER_SRC_PATH}src/libjasper/include \
    ${PNG_SRC_PATH} \
    ${MNG_SRC_PATH} \
    ${JPEG_SRC_PATH} \
    ${LCMS_SRC_PATH}include/ \
    ${TIFF_SRC_PATH}libtiff/ \
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_myproject_MainActivity.c


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have tried the C file as .cpp and used extern "C" in all possible ways no result.
I have also deleted the bin,out,libs and obj folders several times and freshly built.
The code compiles and .so files are made.

But I can't run it this is the log

```
> 08-02 01:59:07.268: E/Trace(1569): error opening trace file: No such
    > file or directory (2) 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to
    > load lib /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libphysfs.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libphysfs.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libphysfs.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libjpeg.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libjpeg.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libjpeg.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libtiff.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libtiff.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libtiff.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libmng.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libmng.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libmng.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libpng.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libpng.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libpng.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libjasper.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libjasper.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libjasper.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/liblcms.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/liblcms.so 0xb63c3518 08-02 01:59:07.268:
    > D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/liblcms.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libdevil.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libdevil.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libdevil.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Trying to load lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libmylib.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): Added shared lib
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libmylib.so 0xb63c3518 08-02
    > 01:59:07.268: D/dalvikvm(1569): No JNI_OnLoad found in
    > /data/data/com.myproject/lib/libmylib.so 0xb63c3518, skipping init
    > 08-02 01:59:07.288: W/dalvikvm(1569): No implementation found for
    > native Lcom/myproject/MainActivity;.convert:()V 08-02 01:59:07.288:
    > D/AndroidRuntime(1569): Shutting down VM 08-02 01:59:07.288:
    > W/dalvikvm(1569): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
    > (group=0xb5e5e288) 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569): FATAL
    > EXCEPTION: main 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):
    > java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
    > com.myproject.MainActivity.convert:()V 08-02 01:59:07.288:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at com.myproject.MainActivity.convert(Native
    > Method) 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > com.myproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    > 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    > 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    > 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    > 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-02 01:59:07.288:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 08-02 01:59:07.288:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    > 08-02 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):   at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 08-02
    > 01:59:07.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1569):     at
    > dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For some reason the method isn't being seen and yet the library is loading....
for what it's worth, I edited this code from [here](https://github.com/hagish/love-native-android) and pulled out what i needed.
Thanx

Comment: run ndk-build -b V=1 and paste the output, the problem is probably in the creating/linking of the library that holds convert.

Answer (score 1):

In the source file you have:

```
Java_com_myproject_ndk_convert
```

But the javah has:

```
Java_com_myproject_MainActivity_convert
```

The log also says:

```
No implementation found for native Lcom/myproject/MainActivity;.convert:
```

Did you mean to write:

```
Java_com_myproject_MainActivity_convert
```

Comment: thanx for pointing that out.I had copied the wrong info.... but now i have edited the question.
Still the error stands